Marriage Law according to Islam
Can I marry my mother’s sister’ daughter according to Islam.

@UmH I have gone through your link twice and still, I am not sure about nieces and nephews. What I read is that is haram to marry aunts or uncles, but I cannot pinpoint if this applies also to sons or daughters of aunts or uncles. In a westerners context, I see this was allowed to assure the ruling class to marry within, for reasons "to keep rulership within the family".

@GyroGearloose This question is about cousins not about nieces. I don't know why you are unsure about nieces after reading the linked question, nieces are mentioned clearly and explicitly in two answers to the linked question. Please search the page.

@UmH thank you, my fault.

Alhamdulillah,
Marrying your mother's sister's daughter (i.e., your maternal first cousin) is permissible in Islam.
This is because she does not fall under your mahaarim i.e., the women that a man is forbidden to marry.
The Prophet ﷺ married his father's sister's daughter (Zaynab bt. Jahsh) who was the daughter of Umaymah bt. Abdul Muttalib, sister of Abdullah b. Abdul Muttalib (the Prophet's father).
And Allah knows best!
